# Sort following information by Id or by Name and display it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.content{
        border: 1px solid gray;
        width: 250px; 
        padding: 5px; 
        margin : 10px;
      }

      .name{                
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #efa520;
        padding: 2px;
      }

      .ids{
        padding: 2px;
        color: #1b8ac1;            
      }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<span>Sort By :</span>
<span>
<select id="sortBy" style="width:80px;" onchange="sortEmp();">
<option value="id">Id
<option value="name">Name
</select>
</span>

<div class="container">
</div>

<script>

var data = {"employees": [
{"208880097" :{"name":"John Doe"}},
{"219087644" : {"name":"Anna Smith"}},
{"980017672" : {"name":"Peter Jones"}},
{"203459867" : {"name":"Christopher Brown"}}
]};

var empData = data.employees;
for(var empId in empData){
  var empInfo = empData[empId];
  for(var id in empInfo){

      var info = empInfo[id];

      var name = info.name;        
      $(".container").append('<div class="content"><span class="name">'+name+'</span><br><span class="ids">'+id+'</span><br></div>')

  }
}

function sortEmp(){
  var sort = $("#sortBy").val();
  if(sort == "name"){
    sortByName();
  }else{
    sortById();
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So I want to sort this information by id or by name on changing select option and according to that dispaly sorted data on view.

There is one option 'Sort By' at the top, so after changing select option 'sortEmp()' function get called, and sorting will be done. So please help me for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this method which will sort your data

```
function sortEmployees(asc, resolver) {
  empData = empData.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = resolver(a), b = resolver(b)
    if (asc) return (a > b) ? 1 : ((a < b) ? -1 : 0)
    else return (b > a) ? 1 : ((b< a) ? -1 : 0)
  }) 
}
```

the first parameter `true` or `false` sets ascending or descending order.

The second parameter is a function (in my example, for ease of use, a lamda), this function has to return the property by which the list should be sorted.

```
// sort by id -  `Object.keys(o)[0]`  returns the id
sortEmployees(true, o => Object.keys(o)[0] )

// sort by name-  `o[Object.keys(o)[0]].name`  returns the name
sortEmployees(true, o => o[Object.keys(o)[0]].name )
```

#### Example

```js
var data = {
  "employees": [{
    "208880097": {
      "name": "John Doe"
    }
  }, {
    "219087644": {
      "name": "Anna Smith"
    }
  }, {
    "980017672": {
      "name": "Peter Jones"
    }
  }, {
    "203459867": {
      "name": "Christopher Brown"
    }
  }]
}

var empData = data.employees;

function displayEmployees() {

  $(".container").html('')

  for (var empId in empData) {
    var empInfo = empData[empId];
    for (var id in empInfo) {

      var info = empInfo[id];

      var name = info.name;
      $(".container").append('<div class="content"><span class="name">' + name + '</span><br><span class="ids">' + id + '</span><br></div>')

    }
  }

}

function sortEmp() {
  var sort = $("#sortBy").val()
  if (sort == "name") {

    sortEmployees(true, o => o[Object.keys(o)[0]].name )
    displayEmployees()

  } else {

    sortEmployees(true, o => Object.keys(o)[0] )
    displayEmployees()
  }
}

function sortEmployees(asc, resolver) {
  empData = empData.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = resolver(a), b = resolver(b)
    if (asc) return (a > b) ? 1 : ((a < b) ? -1 : 0)
    else return (b > a) ? 1 : ((b< a) ? -1 : 0)
  }) 
}

sortEmp()
```

```css
.content {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.name {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #efa520;
  padding: 2px;
}

.ids {
  padding: 2px;
  color: #1b8ac1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Sort By :</span>
<span>
<select id="sortBy" style="width:80px;" onchange="sortEmp();">
<option value="id">Id
<option value="name">Name
</select>
</span>

<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u for this helpful answer. But instead of lamda i.e. o => Object.keys(o)[0]  is there any easy way for this. If any pls let me know

Comment: Sure, you could write `sortEmployees(true, function(o) { return Object.keys(o)[0] })` instead